# dotnet core File.Move issue

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

My Dockerfile is this

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.0

COPY publish/ app/
RUN mkdir -p /in
RUN mkdir -p /tmp

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "app/Watcher.dll"]
```

and I build image with this command

```
docker build -t watcher/sl_user_test:1.1 .
```

so, my docker-compose is this

```
watcher.sl_user_test:
  image: watcher/sl_user_test:1.1
  container_name: watcher_sl_user_test
  build: .
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - /var/storage/in:/in:z
    - /var/storage/tmp:/tmp:z
```

In my dotnet core app I get a file in the /in folder and I move it to /tmp/aaa
code is this

```
string destination = $"/tmp/{Guid.NewGuid()}/git.zip";
new FileInfo(destination).Directory.Create();
File.Move("/in/git.zip", destination, true);
```

the problem is that this command copy file and doesn't move it, why?
If I go inside the container I can do mv from bash and it works

Comment: Can you use File.Delete on the original file? What does File.GetAttributes return? Can the same program read the source of the moved file?

Comment: File.Delete works

Comment: File.GetAttributes says "Normal"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I'm trying to move file from a volume to another.
If you try this code in GoLang you receive this error

```
"rename /dir1/test.txt /dir2/test.txt: invalid cross-device link"
```

So, the solution are

- write your own FileMove function (with copy and delete source)
- use only one volume

So, in my case, from this

```
volumes:
  - /var/storage/in:/in:z
  - /var/storage/tmp:/tmp:z
```

I'll do this

```
volumes:
  - /var/storage/data/:/data:z
```

and in /data there are "in" and "tmp" folders

Answer (score 1):

Since you are creating a new GUID in the path, the directory is guaranteed to not exist already.  Thus `File.Move` will throw a `DirectoryNotFoundException`.

Create it before you move the file.

```
var tmpDir = $"/tmp/{Guid.NewGuid()}";
Directory.CreateDirectory(tmpDir);
File.Move("/in/git.zip", $"{tmpDir}/git.zip", true);
```

Assuming you are doing that, if the `File.Move` method just does a copy instead of a move, then it is likely that the original file is in use.  From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.move?view=netcore-3.0#System_IO_File_Move_System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_) (in the *Remarks* section):

> If you try to move a file across disk volumes and that file is in use, the file is copied to the destination, but it is not deleted from the source.

Comment: This is a good tips, but I use this function to verify if file is in use, and always isn't lock https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876473/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-file-is-in-use

Comment: If I run the application directly (without docker) File.Move works